# How do we tell arithemetic addition or subtraction from floating point numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, floating-point

[image]

Source: C++ for Engineers and Scientists, Gary J. Bronson

[image]

Source: Programmable Logic Controllers: The Complete Guide to the Technology by Clarence T. Jones
In the table $12345.67_{10}$ = 1.234567+04 (floating point), 1.234567+04 doesn't show any difference between the arithematic addition notation, so if the author was not saying "floating point", I would assume 1.234567+04 equals 5.234567, not 12345.67. So how do we differentiate arithemetic addition or subtraction from floating point numbers?

Comment: Yes, the notation as in this table is unpleasant. Either the typical $1.234567E{+04}$ or a specific tuple notation such as $(1.234567,+04)$ should be used if one might encounter those beasts out of context. Not to mention, that likely the *rel* floating point representation you encounter will all use binary exponents

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What does "rel floating point representation" mean?